# Difference between installed packages of GCC compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

After I installed the gcc cross compiler on my ubuntu, I noticed a few new packages.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++             
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8
```

Both packages compile my code correctly. I suspect that one compiler is a version independent (ie once i install version 4.9 this package would still be named as it is) and one is specifically for version 4.8 only.

What could be the difference between the following two packages and which one I should use to cross compile in  eclipse?

Comment: I expect they are not different packages, but different links to the same compiler - in other words, `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` is a link to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8` - if you install another version, the link will be set up to point to the new one, but you can, if you want to be specific, still use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8` to compile with that specific compiler.

Comment: I suspected the same